# notification not closing in javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, notifications

There I have a php while loop where I am selecting everything from a mysqli database and then displaying it on a javascript notification but when I close the notification and refresh the page it comes up again how do I prevent the notification from coming up again when I close it and refresh the page. Here is my code

```
<?php 
    $select_children_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM parent_help");
    while($select_children = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_children_query)) {
        ?>
             <script>

                function notifyMe() {
                  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
                    alert("This browser does not support system notifications");
                  }
                  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                    notify();
                  }
                  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
                    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
                      if (permission === "granted") {
                        notify();
                      }
                    });
                  }

                  function notify() {
                    var notification = new Notification('TITLE OF NOTIFICATION', {
                      icon: 'http://carnes.cc/jsnuggets_avatar.jpg',
                      body: "Hey! You are on notice!",
                    });

                    notification.onclick = function () {
                      window.open("http://carnes.cc");      
                    };
                  }

                }
                notifyMe();
            </script>

        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Take the `notifyMe()` call outside the loop, so it's only called once.

Comment: Why do you have a loop at all? You're not doing anything with `$select_children`.

Comment: You're also redefining the functions every time through the loop. A function can only have one definition.

Comment: hello @Barmar could you please give me your version of my code thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What's the purpose of the database query and the loop?>

Comment: The question says you're displaying everything from the database query in the notification, but you're not using anything from the query.